# How to terminate process inside EShell mode?

Tags: emacs

#### Background Information

I am using *Spacemacs* as my default configuration. I am running a JavaScript infinite loop inside my EShell using Node.js. In the regular terminal, I usually terminate it by using `C-c`. What should I do inside EShell?

I have read the section about shell mode and terminal emulator in the Emacs doc, but find no help and related command to terminate the process.

#### Question

How can I terminatr the process inside EShell-mode without restarting the editor? Although restarting the editor *does* solve the issue.

Even killing the buffer does not work. Oh dear, it is still running.

Comment: Do you mean *terminate?* Does C-c C-c not work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Solution

`C-c C-c`, eshell-interrupt-process.

Huge thanks to @tripleee.